# regular expression for validating email addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

I have the following expression

```
**replacePattern3 = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;
   replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');**
```

but it doesn't validate email if the email in this form  a.b@alexmed.com  it only validate email in form a@alexmed.com

i need another expression to validate the form a.b@alexmed.com

Answer (score 0):

I think \w+ is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9], so it doesn't like the dot. I'm not good at this, but try

```
**replacePattern3 = /(\[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;
```

You also might want to add a few more symbols to most places, because domain names can have numbers and certain symbols in them.